# How can I use iCloud with 2 different apple ID's?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, icloud

My problem is that my dad has an iPad and I have an iPhone. He uses a different apple id for his own iPad and I use my own for my own iPhone. I do have home sharing and have them linked to the same homesharing id. But my problem is when I type a paper with pages or make something in keynote the iCloud doesn't work. If I make something on his iPad and save it, I want it to show up on my iPhone. I always have to email it to myself. Can anyone help me please? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you inferring when you mentioned "iCloud doesn't work"? And "save it it wound show up on my iPhone" - does this mean that you would like to create a Pages or Keynote document on his iPad and have it sync automatically to your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate apple IDs for iCloud and iTunes.
 Homesharing, iTunes Match, along with iTunes/App Stores can all be associated with a shared iTunes account Apple ID.

SETTINGS>> iTunes and App stores>>

iCloud iMessage and FaceTime can be signed into with your own unique Apple IDs. A total of 2 Apple IDs are all that are needed between you and your dad.

Settings>> iCloud>> delete account off one device and keep info when prompted to keep or delete.

If personal info such as contacts, calendars, bookmarks etc, have been merged with Info from other device it would be wise to clean up these items before signing into the different Apple ID.